# AWS CodeDeploy role with IAM role is not worked

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-iam, continuous-deployment

I am creating CI/CD pipeline in ec2 instance from my github private repository. I have follow same steps which id given in  [aws documentaion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/error-codes.html). (`error code: IAM_ROLE_PERMISSIONS`) But when I am trying to create deployment group then its give me error

```
AWS CodeDeploy does not have the permissions required to assume the role 'Service role arn'
```

for the Service role filed.

Comment: Can you show the IAM role? Specially its trust policy?

Comment: Sure please have look [https://prnt.sc/u9gahs]

Comment: @Marcin Let me know  any more info you required!

Comment: What about instance roles? They also need special permissions as show [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html).

Comment: @Marcin I have allow all resources as well as Action for s3 bucket.  so that till give me error.